# In Appcelerator, how to add image in navigation bar (for Android app) and event listener for that image

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am newbie in Titanium Appcelerator. I am building an App for Android.I have a requirement to add two icons in nav bar of app:

1. Home Icon with click event to go back to home page.
2. AppIcon in the nav bar

I seen that there is similar properties available for iOS like below:

- titleImage : String
- toolbar : Object[]
- titleControl

**Sample Code**

```
var titleLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            backgroundImage :'/logo.png',
            height : 34,
            width:  193, 
        });
$.clientMainScreenWin.setTitleControl(titleLabel);
```

Is there any approach for Android app

Answer (score 2):

For Android you'd use the [Titanium.Android.ActionBar](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar)